# Get Wrong Query when usin MIN in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an table like this

[image: table]

I have been try this sql code

```
SELECT id,lat,lng,name,MIN(hitung) AS Smallest FROM open_list;
```

but the result give me wrong query

[image: wrong]

what i wanna do is being like this :

[image: reall]

Comment: When you apply an aggregate function without a GROUP BY, the other values selected by MySQL can be indeterminate. Read the docs -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html  What is the logic that you want to return those specific values?

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get over the way MySQL does this. That query simply shouldn't run. Instead it makes semi-random choices for you.

Comment: @Andrew In some cases - well, lots of cases - it makes it easier. However, the potential for abuse is high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT id,lat,lng,name,hitung
FROM open_list
ORDER BY hitung ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Or, if you want to do more complex stuff, start with this:

```
SELECT id,lat,lng,name,hitung
FROM open_list
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(hitung) as hitung
    FROM open_list
) tmp USING (hitung)
```

Comment: `DESC` should be `ASC` since OP is after minimum.

Comment: @GoatCO Indeed it should. *fixes*

Answer (score 1):

When you do not `GROUP BY` non-aggregate values from your `SELECT` list, the returned values are arbitrary.  You can add a `GROUP BY` but that will return multiple records, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get what you're after:

```
SELECT id,lat,lng,name,hitung
FROM open_list
GROUP BY id,lat,lng,name
ORDER BY hitung ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That will result in multiple rows, not one row.